# cloud-init is using domains given in DHCP for hostname

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel, cloud-init

In AWS VPC, I am associating the following as DHCP

```
Domain name server: 10.*.*.2 (VPC DNS)
Domain Name: ec2.internal privatedomain_1.com privatedomain_2.com publicdomain.com
```

Due to which the hostname is getting set up as `ip-10-5-*-*.privatedomain_1.comprivatedomain_2.compublicdomain.com`
the above is the combination of all 3 Domains names given in DHCP.

The reason to add the domains to DHCP is to only effect `/etc/resolv.conf` and not the hostname but it is not working as expected, also it is adding a combination of these entries in `/etc/resolv.conf as well

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search ec2.internal privatedomain_1.com privatedomain_2.com publicdomain.com 
 privatedomain_1.comprivatedomain_2.compublicdomain.com
nameserver 10.*.*.2
```

I have tried using the preserve hostname document provided by AWS and cloud-init

1. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/linux-static-hostname-rhel-centos-amazon/
2. [How do I stop cloud-init from overwriting my hostname on AWS (CentOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113380/how-do-i-stop-cloud-init-from-overwriting-my-hostname-on-aws-centos)
3. https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#set-hostname.

but these didn't work out, Any suggestions?